# Azure, how long should I have to wait before reataching a datadisk?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

After detaching a datadisk on a Azure's virtual machine, I can't reatache it just after on Azure, and I found my datadisk in the disk tab is still attaching to my vm(but in the vm tab it's not).

I would like to ask on general, how long I have to wait in my program before I can authorize the reatachement??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, this can take up to 10 minutes, though usually it will be much faster than that.